# Access Denied for User ODBC

Tags: cmd, windows-7, odbc, mysql

i installed Mysql on Windows 7, i used mysql with mysql command line client & i also use Mysqldump in windows cmd, it was working without any problem.
But today, i tried to export database using mysqldump with this command in cmd

```
mysqldump –u root -p mypassword db_name > f:\mydb.sql
```

i tried many other commands and i always see error

```
Access Denied for User 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: yes) when trying to connect
```

as you can see, in mysqldump command i am using root as user then why i get user ODBC error ? one more thing, using mysql command line client i am still using mysql normally without any problem using root as user. Thanks

Comment: what code you are looking for? i am using cmd and here is my command to export database  mysqldump –u root -p mypassword db_name > f:\mydb.sql

Comment: first connect t server. `mysql –u root -p mypassword` and try to connect

Comment: in cmd first i changed directory with cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin then i used this command mysqldump –u root -p mypassword and i was asked for password i entered password again and pressed Enter, but still i see same error Access Denied for User 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: yes) when trying to connect

Comment: your password is wrong thats the error then

Comment: but using same password i am able to login to mysql using "mysql command line client" and 2nd thing error is saying about user ODBC not root.

Comment: that problem is with your user name and  password